# Replacing '(' with '( ' if it's not inside quotes

Tags: regex, replace, regex-negation

Let's say I have some text like this:

```
(what)
```

and

```
"(what)"
```

I'm trying to replace `(` by `([space]` if it's not inside quotes.
So after substitution the first string should look like this:

```
( what)
```

and second string shouldn't be changed.

I tried `[^"]\([^"]` but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you have nested parenthesis? Can this happen `(some (text))`?

Comment: Anytime you're trying to do things based on whether or not some bit of text falls inside a pair of delimiters like quotation marks, you're getting into complex territory and should perhaps consider a different tool than regular expressions. Especially if those delimiters can potentially be nested, or contain quoted instances of themselves.

Comment: @Vache Yes. That can happen too.

Comment: @MarkReed Can You suggest some other tools?

Comment: Have you tried a [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bregex%5D+parentheses+quoted)?

Comment: @SPython: Can you have escaped quotes also like: `(some "abcd (some \"(text))")`

Comment: @SPython can you post more samples to know what types of strings you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can help yourself using lookarounds.

You can use this regex:

```
^(?!").*(\()
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/zJ7kB6/2)**

Btw, you can also use the discard technique:

```
.*?".*?".*?|(\()
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/zJ7kB6/3)**

Comment: what about ending double quote?

Comment: It wasn't explicitly in OPs requirements, but this wouldn't work for something like "start of quote (parens)", assuming they wouldn't want the space there.

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia good point. Thanks for show me that. Let me fix it

Answer (score 0):

You can try with Look-ahead and Look-behind

```
(?<!")\(([^)]+)(?!\)")
```

Replacement with `( $1`

[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/kR1eR4/4)

Answer (score 0):

Try this method with Notepad++
first time
replace "(   with (  (paretse flow by space)

second replace )"  with   space)

and will work fine